# Как сделать перенос строк в операторе echo?

Tags: php, html

Как сделать перенос строк с помощью конструкции `echo` в php? `\n` - не работает, хоть и написан в мануале, работает только тег html `<br>`.

Работаю в Win7 64x, xampp.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Разметка HTML игнорирует переводы строк, за исключением предварительно форматированного текста.

```
<pre> ...</pre>
```

Для переноса строки используйте тэг:

```
<br/>
```

Эта особенность- базовая основа html. Нужно всегда помнить, что внутри текстовых узлов множество подряд следующих пробельных символов будет отображаться как один пробел.

Это поведение можно изменить, как указано выше тэгом `pre`, либо свойством css `white-space: pre`.
Подробная информация в справочнике: 
https://webref.ru/css/white-space

Comment: Спасибо буду знать, html знаю, верстал, просто не хотелось вставлять туда теги) Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для конвертации переносов строк в видимые `<br />` в php есть специальная функция:

> string [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php)(string $string [, bool $is_xhtml=true])

```
$text = "Line 1\nLine 2\n";
echo nl2br($text); // Line 1<br />\nLine 2<br />\n
```

[3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/r0NJl)

Answer (score 0):

Для тех кто будет читать этот текст через годы. Дополню немного. Нужно различать перевод строки как команду браузера, и перевод строки для оформления исходного текста. Вот про отображение ответили отлично. А про оформление исходного может возникнуть проблемка мелкая. '\n' отобразит в исходнике именно \n т.е. два символа, а "\n" переведёт строку и код страницы будет писаться с новой строки. Пожалуйста самый очевидный пример:

```
echo '<li>'.$list['title'].'</li>'
```

Выведет в исходник в одну строчку все тэги. Что конечно работает, но коллега Вас проклянёт если будет смотреть код без вспомогательных средств.
А вот:

```
echo '<li>'.$list['title'].'</li>'."\n";
```

аккуратненько разделит список на строчки.

Comment: Это коллегу проклинать надо тогда. За то, что он код инспектирует не через девтулзы или форматирующие HTML инструменты, а через `view-source`. А минусы вам наставили потому, что вы рекомендуете полную ерунду - никто не форматирует выплёвываемый код, его наоборот **минифицируют** без лишних пробелов и переносов строк. Главное, чтобы исходники выглядели нормально и были читаемыми.

Comment: Между прочем заминусован без основательно по моему мнению, лишний отступ и перевод строки производительности не навредит вообще никак, а смотреть на нормально отформатированный код во всяком случае иногда для отладки нужно.

Comment: @NikitaBogdanov производительности - нет, а вот верстке (например, при верстке писем или при каком-нибудь старом IE) - да.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php echo "первая строка<br>вторая срока"; ?>
```

А самый очевидный вариант почему не устраивает?

Answer (score -2):

Можно сделать так

```
echo ' <br/>';
```

Comment: Не глючит она. Зачем этот ничем не отличающийся от других, ответ тут? // Надо бы свой написать)

Comment: ответ как раз не такой как все остальные, меньше всего тегов

Comment: у меня \n не работает ни в кавычках. ни в двойных, ни со слешем.